# Symfony / Fixtures "Reference already exists, use method setReference in order to override it"

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fixtures

I created 2 fixtures files and want to link them but got the error :  Reference to "genre_reference" already exists, use method setReference in order to override it.

Here is my book fixtures :

```
class LivreFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $faker = Factory::create('fr_FR');
        $faker->seed(123);

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $livre = new Livre();
            $livre->setTitre($faker->sentence($nbWords = 4, $variableNbWords = true));
            $livre->setAuteur($faker->name);
            $livre->setDescription($faker->text);
            $livre->setDateDeParution($faker->dateTime($format = 'Y-m-d'));
            $livre->setGenre($this->getReference('genre_reference'));
            $manager->persist($livre);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return array(
            GenreFixtures::class,
        );
    }
}
```

And my genre fixtures file :

```
class GenreFixtures extends Fixture
{

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $faker = Factory::create('fr_FR');
        $faker->seed(123);
        
        for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
          $genre = new Genre();
          $genre->setName($faker->colorName);
          $manager->persist($genre);
          $this->addReference('genre_reference', $genre);
        }

      $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

I don't really understand the setreference method, how to do it. Any help ?

Comment: Did you clear cache test ?

Comment: iI can't I have a new error appearing "Invalid "af 2" locale. Tried to rename to manually cache clear but nothing works and don't know why suddenly this error came.

Comment: I think you should fix this error first cause your code should work

Comment: Yes thank you I try to fix that but can't really find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add **$i** to your genre reference name.

```php
$this->addReference('genre_reference_' . $i, $genre);
```

After that, you can use it by

```php
$this->getReference('genre_reference_0');
//OR
$this->getReference('genre_reference_1');
//OR
$this->getReference('genre_reference_' . $i);
```